# How to read data from a .txt file into an ArrayList to create objects

Tags: java, parsing, arraylist, exception, polymorphism

I have designed a program that reads information(customers and courses) off of two text file documents and place them into their respective ArrayList.
For example course data looks like this:

```
output.format("%s;%s;%s;%.2f;%s;%s;%s;%s;%b;%d;%s\r\n","Online","Java1","Davis",125.00," 1/1/2015"," 2/1/2015"," programming"," UTA ", true,12," Jones");
```

**Notice the name of the customer "Jones" is placed at the end of the string of data so that I know which course goes to which customer.**

And customer data looks like this:

```
output.format("%s;%d;%s;%s;%s;%d;%d;%s\r\n","Jones",786,"Cooper","Arlington","Texas",76019,12345,"student");
```

**Notice that the `customerType` is placed at the end the string of data.**

The first file is called **customers.txt** and I use a `readCustomers` method, located in my test case, which reads the **customers.txt** file, creates customers using the data, and adds them to an ArrayList called `customerList`.

```
ArrayList<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
```

The second file is called **courses.txt** and I use a `readCourses` method, also located in my test case) which reads the the file, creates courses using the data, and finally adds the courses to their respective/correct customer. I utilize a second ArrayList called `courseList` to achieve this.

```
ArrayList<Course> courseList = new ArrayList<Course>();
```

I have 7 other classes in this program: Date,Time,Customer,Course,OnLineCourse,InClassCourse,Invoice(interface).

After customers are loaded with their respective customer, a method called `generateInvoice` calls method `createInvoice` in class `customer` which calculates the invoice for each customer and finally printing it out to a `dialog box` under the headings **Name, Account, and Total**

**My problem is that I do not know how to create new customers from the `customers.txt` file and add them to `customerList`**

My attempt at `readCustomers` method looks like this:

```
public static void readCustomers()
{
    Scanner input;
    String sentence;
    String values[];

    try
    {
        input = new Scanner(new File("customer.txt"));
        while(input.hasNext())
        {
            sentence = input.nextLine();
            values = sentence.split(";");
            for(Customer c:customerList)
            {
                if((c.getName().equals(values[9])))
                {
                  customerList.add(new Customer(values[0],createAddress(values[1]),Integer.parseInt(values[2])));                   
                }
           }  
        }    
    }
```

// there is a catch block in my program

Comment: You don't seem to have declared customerList anywhere. What error do you get when you run the code you posted?

Comment: @CalumMcCall  `CustomerList` is declared in the test case at the top.

Comment: @CalumMcCall errors look like this: {java.io.FileNotFoundException: customers.txt (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
 at customertest.CustomerTest.readCustomers(CustomerTest.java:28)
 at customertest.CustomerTest.main(CustomerTest.java:15)}

Comment: @CalumMcCall and theses: {java.io.FileNotFoundException: courses.txt (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
 at customertest.CustomerTest.readCourses(CustomerTest.java:57)
 at customertest.CustomerTest.main(CustomerTest.java:16)}

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: courses.txt (No such file or directory)` ...

Comment: @Tom what does that mean?

Comment: It means that there is no **courses.txt** file available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to make sure the "customer.txt" file is in the right place, if you have a `FileNotFoundException`...

Then several things in the code above:

- When I read the example of customer line, I count **11** properties. I'm wondering what you test in `if((c.getName().equals(values[9])))`; it doesn't look like the name of the customer.
- You are reading in a list `customerList` which - guessing here - contains the list of `Customer` with only the name set, and you want to create a list of `Customer` beans with the additional information found in the file.

If this is the intention,

- either you need to create *another* list and `add` a new instance of `Customer` initialised with the properties read from the file. The function `readCustomers()` should return the new `List<Customer>`.
- or you want to *update* the `Customer` bean instances that are in the `customerList`. But in this case, you have nothing to add to the list. You just need to get each bean instance, set the properties, and continue. At the end of the function, the `customerList` shall be updated.